# what is a better approach for adding back a soft deleted data, create a new entry or restore the deleted data

Tags: database, unique-key, soft-delete

I am using soft delete to delete an entry from a database table.

If I want to add the same data again, what would be a better approach: to create a new entry or restore the deleted data?

What will be the unique key constraint behavior with the first approach?

Comment: It depends on your requirements but the first approach (update the soft delete flag so that it's no longer deleted) is by far the simplest. Simple solutions are often the best.

Comment: shall I audit the change in that case, because otherwise, the information regarding the delete will not be available anymore

Comment: If it is a requirement to audit the change - certainly. Software development is driven by requirements (or forward thinking people identifying things before they become requirements)

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS The 1st question cannot be answered without you giving requirements & cost/benefit by which to choose. And after you say, how/why are you stuck choosing? [ask] [Help] [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Restoring data would be correct and simple to do if you are talking about something like a user, in which you can validate the identity with a password or some other authentication method. But if it is another table where you cannot be sure about the true identity, then the best approach would be to create a new entry.

Another case is where you need to keep something of the sorts of an Archive. An example: You have a **Client** and a **Contract** table with a M:M relationship, so you create a **bridge table**, let's call it **ContractClient**, to store the data and have a 1:M towards that bridge table. So, a client can only have an active contract at a time but that contract could be terminated later on, which will be "archived" in the database with an active status of false. That client can have another contract in the future with an active status of true, one and only one, but in the database that client has had previous contracts which were not deleted but stored for future use by the administration, think of data mining or whatever. In this case we create a new record and we do not edit the previous contract, since we want to have an archive of the previous contract activity of our clients.

So, in summary, it depends in your use case or business logic you want to implement. In some cases you can reuse a previous record and in some others you should not.